# How we can identify the position of the character at keydown event?

Tags: angular, ionic3

At keydown event, i am not able to determine the position of the newly inserted character.
is there anyway to know the position?

Comment: `console.log(event.selectionStart)`  ?

Comment: Posting as answer for anyone who stumbles across this ! Kindly accept :)

Answer (score 0):

**To know the position of the cursor on the keydown/keyup events we need `selectionStart` from `$event`**

```
  yourEvent(event) {
    const characterPosition = event.selectionStart;
    console.log('The cursor position on keydown is:', characterPosition);
  }
```